# Rename the tag [azure-web-sites] to [azure-web-apps]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The technology was renamed a couple years ago, and [azure-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-apps) is already there as a synonym. But it would reduce confusion if we could make [azure-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-apps) the *primary* tag, and move [azure-web-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites) to be a synonym.

Can we do this, without breaking people who are listening on this tag?

Comment: Any chance to have this particular item reviewed? At this point the term "Azure Web Sites" (and related tag `azure-web-sites`) is no longer a referenced term in any Azure documentation; it's officially been "Azure Web Apps" for a few years now. It would really be helpful to swap the tag priority.

Comment: Yeah, this never got traction. I guess I don't really understand how the approval process works.